# Storing secret env variables as separate data container in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use 'secret' (passwords etc) env variables from host OS inside docker-compose.

I thought it is possible to achieve this using data container. But it is not working - 'No file present'. Please advice what is wrong and if this doable this way.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec puma
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - RACK_ENV=production
      - RAILS_ENV=production
    volumes_from:
      - config
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db

  config:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - /myapp/config/.env:.env
```

I also tried to use `/myapp/config:/config` as volume and `/config/.env` as env_file but with same result.

Dockerfile doesnt mention or reference 'config' or '.env' in any way.

Thanks for responses.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about why you are trying to do host mapped file -> config continer -> web container? Why not just mapped file -> web container?

Comment: Also, if the container process just needs the environment variables available in the environment (as opposed to the actual file), you can map host environment variables through the Compose YAML right into the container (as if you did `-e`). I'm happy to create an answer with an example of this if this is truly what you are after.

Comment: If you have an env variable, it's already not secret - there are likely multiple copies of it in memory of more than one process. If you are concerned about hiding it from other entities on the system, use configuration files or dedicated facilities with highly restricted access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Compose env file

The `env_file` file is read locally by `docker-compose`, in the directory you are running it from. The variables are then passed to the containers at run time (like `docker run -e`).

```
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec puma
  env_file: ./.env
  environment:
    - RACK_ENV=production
    - RAILS_ENV=production
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

#### Substitution

Compose can also [substitute environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) into the config

If you have `SECRET_HOST_ENV_VARIABLE` set on your host when you run `docker-compose` with an environment definition like below

```
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec puma
  environment:
    - RACK_ENV=production
    - RAILS_ENV=production
    - SECRET_ENV_VARIABLE=${SECRET_HOST_ENV_VARIABLE}
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

`SECRET_ENV_VARIABLE` will become available in the containers environment.